# Rails—Select dropdown email to choose user for associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form to update a `Jog`, which belongs to a user. I want the admin to be able to edit the user, but instead of typing in a `user_id`, I want to select the user's email from a dropdown menu.

```
= form_for @jog, remote: true do |f|

  h2 "Edit Record"
  table.ui.single.line.table
    tb
      tr
        td
          .ui.input
            = f.text_field :distance, placeholder: "distance (meters)"
        td
          .ui.input
            = f.text_field :time, placeholder: "time (minutes)"
        - if(current_user.admin?)
          td
            .ui.input
              = f.text_field :user_id, placeholder: "User ID"
        td = f.submit "Update", class: "ui button"
```

The above is what I have so far, and it works automatically because `user_id` is a field in `Jog`. But how would I populate the edit form with an email address, and when I submit the form how would I convert that to the `user_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to have a select dropdown with one field visible, but another passed to the form:

```
 = f.select :user_id, User.all.map{|u| [u.email, u.id]}, {}, { class: "ui compact selection dropdown" }
```

The class stuff is for Semantic UI, it's not necessary if you aren't using that framework.

Answer (score 0):

The css classes defined here is from Semantic UI. The search class makes it easy for you to search the dropdown. While the `{selected: @jog.user-id}` option keeps the user selected anytime you decide to edit that field.

```
<%= f.select(:user_id , User.all.collect { |user| [ user.email, user.id ] }, {selected: @jog.user_id}, {class: "ui dropdown search"} ) %>
```